# Configure settings.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

Anyone have idea where we have to configure settings.xml file when moving maven project to gradle in Android studio.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Gradle will use maven's dependency management in the background.  You can include your local maven repository `~/.m2` by supplying it to the `repositories` closure

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    ...
}
```